# Finding number of ways to get a sum of $100$

Tags: combinatorics

If we are given to find the number of ways 10 positive integers can sum to 50, we simply find the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in $(x+x^2+...+x^{90})^{10}$, which turns out to be $\binom{99}{90}$.

But what do we do if we are asked to find the ways if the numbers are distinct? How do we proceed then? Can we use a generating functions approach? I have thought a lot, but didn't cup up with anything doable. Please help me out.

Comment: Well in particular, there are no 10 distinct positive integers with sum 50. Clearly the ten distinct numbers $1, \dots, 10$ have the smallest possible sum, but $1+\cdots+10 = \frac{10\cdot 11}2 = 55 > 50$.

Comment: @BenFrankel Alright, I'll make it five.

Comment: @BenFrankel Infact, I'll make the sum 100

Comment: Related: [The number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts equals the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54961/the-number-of-partitions-of-n-into-distinct-parts-equals-the-number-of-partiti).

Comment: Are you imposing two constraints on a partition of $n=100$, namely the number of parts (10) and the distinctness of the parts?

Comment: @hardmath You could think of it that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generating function approach is possible, but first let's note that if $q(n,k)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts and $p(n,k)$ denotes the partition of $n$ into exactly $k$ (not necessarily distinct) parts, then:

$$ q(n,k) = p\left(n - \binom{k}{2}, k\right) $$

For details see [this Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306008/3111) to the previously asked [Partition an integer $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/partition-an-integer-n-into-exactly-k-distinct-parts), which however does not go into the generating function aspect.

We are therefore able to translate the generating function for $p(n,k)$ already noted in the Question to one for $q(n,k)$.  In particular, since $q(100,10) = p(55,10)$, this should be the coefficient of $x^{55}$ in:

$$ \frac{x^{10}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\ldots(1-x^{10})} $$

According to Henry Bottomley's [Partition and composition calculator](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm) (may require browser permissions for Java applet to run), this number is $33401$.

Since the generating function for $p(n,k)$ is:

$$ P_k(x) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} p(n,k)x^n = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\ldots(1-x^k)} $$

the generating function for $q(n,k)$ is:

$$ Q_k(x) = \sum_{n=k(k+1)/2}^{\infty} p\left(n - \binom{k}{2},k\right)x^n $$

$$ = x^{\binom{k}{2}} \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} p\left(m,k\right)x^m $$

$$ = \frac{x^{k(k+1)/2}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\ldots(1-x^k)} $$

The same conclusion is reached at [Partitions Into Distinct Parts (MathPages)](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath556/kmath556.htm).