# Partitions of 100 into 10 parts having DIFFERENT size

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many partitions of 100 into 10 parts are there with all parts having DIFFERENT sizes?

I tried brute force, but ill take to long, and i can't find a Simple way to get it.

I was thinking in summation with (i) ... But i can't reach the answer.

Comment: If the parts are $p_1<p_2<\dots<p_10$, then the differences $d_1=p_1$, $d_k = p_k-p_{k-1}$ are positive integers satisfying $10d_1+9d_2+8d_3+\cdots+d_{10}=100$; equivalently, if $c_k=d_k-1$, then the $c_k$ are nonnegative integers satisfying $10c_1+9c_2+8c_3+\cdots+c_{10}=45$. Counting such solutions should be pretty easy by looping over the variables.

Comment: So what i want os p(100,10)?

Comment: How i do a summation of i=1 to k? Of p(10,i)??? Is that correct?

Comment: Can we use inclusion-exclusion principle ?

Comment: You can try with that

Comment: Like I said yesterday, $p$ as a function in this context is the name for the function where we **don't** care about the part sizes being distinct.  You want to use the letter **Q**, not the letter **P** here... you want $q(100,10)$ in order to emphasize the part sizes being distinct.

Comment: Like I said yesterday, [this is a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/partition-an-integer-n-into-exactly-k-distinct-parts).  Like I said yesterday, you can find more information [on mathworld.wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html), scrolling down the page to where it talks about $q(n,k)$.  See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980872/finding-number-of-ways-to-get-a-sum-of-100?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition an integer $n$ into exactly $k$ distinct parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/partition-an-integer-n-into-exactly-k-distinct-parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence https://oeis.org/A008289 contains a table of the number of ways to split an integer n into k parts of different size. It gives a recursive formula which produces 33401 in row 100 and column 10 of the table:

```
  1 
  1   1 
  1   1   0 
  1   2   0   0 
  1   2   1   0   0 
  1   3   1   0   0   0 
  1   3   2   0   0   0   0 
  1   4   3   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   4   4   1   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   5   5   1   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   5   7   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   6   8   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   6  10   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   7  12   6   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   7  14   9   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   8  16  11   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   8  19  15   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   9  21  18   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
  1   9  24  23   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```